# Performing long running UI changes without blocking the main thread

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, backgroundworker

Is there anyway to run a large number of UI updates without effecting the main thread in a C# winforms application?

I would like to avoid a long delay when a user clicks a specific event (which in my case is many close form calls to dispose of memory)

I know i can use `BackgroundWorker` to perform lengthy operations in the "do work" event, but the problem is that you cant change any UI in this event (it will cause a cross thread exception) - so i cant put my large number of close form calls here.

And I cant put the close form calls in the "worker completed" event because this is run on the main thread, and will eventually lockup the main thread causing a bad user experience.

I have thought about spawning a thread to handle closes only when the appication session is idle, but not sure if this is going to be a bit messy.

Comment: Why are the close form calls taking so much time?   What are you doing that is time consuming.

Comment: Can you split out single heavy operation into multiple small and then dispatch to UI thread so UI thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event of [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4852et58.aspx) to update UI. To enable this feature set [WorkerReportsProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress.aspx) property of your [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4852et58.aspx) instance to `true`. Then you can update UI many times by sending data from [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) event handler:

```
backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(percentage, yourCustomData);
```

It is recommended to [Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Here is the reason:

> Access to Windows Forms controls is not inherently thread safe. If you
>   have two or more threads manipulating the state of a control, it is
>   possible to force the control into an inconsistent state. Other
>   thread-related bugs are possible as well, including race conditions
>   and deadlocks. It is important to ensure that access to your controls
>   is done in a thread-safe way.
>
> The .NET Framework helps you detect when you are accessing your
>   controls in a manner that is not thread safe. When you are running
>   your application in the debugger, and a thread other than the one
>   which created a control attempts to call that control, the debugger
>   raises an InvalidOperationException with the message, "Control control
>   name accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."
>
> This exception occurs reliably during debugging and, under some
>   circumstances, at run time. You are strongly advised to fix this
>   problem when you see it.

You can disable that exception:

```
Form.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

But controls could (and sometime will) stop working.

Comment: but is this also run on the main thread? from what i have read, progress changed and completed events are run on the main thread

Comment: Any update of UI will run on main thread (thread, in which controls where created) - winforms controls are not thread safe

Comment: thanks, i figured this was the case. so in my scenario i cant do much, the user will get a delay even when ProgressChanged is called? or will it be a delay they wont notice because the thread is only changed periodically?

Comment: If you allow for sleep in between the ProgressChanged events, the user will not notice...