# How to make a progressbar run in a different thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I want to create a basic multi-thread application using a progress bar. Meaning that this progress bar will run on a different thread while the main thread is busy in the large process it is doing. I've seen a lot of tutorials about it. But the thing that they are multi-threading is the one that doing the large process. The progress bar in the other form is just showing a simple progress bar that runs and complete using a timer.

This is the code I have now.

For the thread:

```
public void thread()
{
  Form6 for6 = new Form6();
  for6.Show();
}


TH1 = new Thread(thread);
TH1.Start();
```

For the progress bar (Code inside form 6)

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Increment(+1);
        if (progressBar1.Value == 99)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void Form6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

My problem is the thread in here doesn't run the Form6. Is there any way for me to do this?

Comment: Forms can only work in single-threaded apartment (STA).

Comment: @gabba so it is not possible??

Comment: Whats happening? Is the second form showing up or not?

Comment: I answer the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206926/vb-net-progressbar-backgroundworker/13486676#13486676) - you can use a code converter to get it in C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the `ProgressBar`, you should really move your long-running, non-UI code into a separate thread. The standard and easier way of doing this in WinForms is to use `BackgroundWorker` component, which can raise `ProgressChanged` event where you can update your UI. Important to note that `ProgressChanged` event is raised on the UI thread, not on the worker thread, so you don't even need to use `Invoke()` to perform UI operations (such as updating your ProgressBar).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using main thread for large processing you can  use the Background worker for all the processing.

Here's a simple example to do it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();       
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = "";
            label2.Text = "";
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);
            bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgw_ProgressChanged);
            bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgw_RunWorkerCompleted);
            bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int total = 57; //some number (this is your variable to change)!!

            for (int i = 0; i <= total; i++) //some number (total)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                int percents = (i * 100) / total;
                bgw.ReportProgress(percents, i);
                //2 arguments:
                //1. procenteges (from 0 t0 100) - i do a calcumation 
                //2. some current value!
            }
        }

        void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            label1.Text = String.Format("Progress: {0} %", e.ProgressPercentage);
            label2.Text = String.Format("Total items transfered: {0}", e.UserState);
        }

        void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
             //do the code when bgv completes its work
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you must use [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) for avoid cross-threading problem,but I prefer use `BackgroundWorker` for resolve it, create `Form6` on a `_field` and use progressbar in `ProgressChanged` event for more information see this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)

```
public void thread()
       {
          Form6 for6=null;
          Application.OpenForms[0].Control.Invoke(delegate{
            for6 = new Form6();
            for6.Show();
      });
   }
```

Comment: thanks but the code you provide at the top seems to have a problem. The error I got is this "Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: @LucasJuan. use typecast to `Action` for convert anonymous method,`Control.Invoke((Action)delegate{`

Comment: there is still something sir Error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate)'

Comment: How can I make it static?

Comment: use `Application.OpenForms[0].Invoke`