# Installing SQL Server Express 2008 using VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008 using vb.net, run SQL Script and backgroundworker

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Dim pro1 As System.Diagnostics.Process
    pro1 = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    pro1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    pro1.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD"
    pro1.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C SQLExpr_x64_enu.exe /QUIET=""TRUE"" /q /ACTION=Install /SkipRules=VSShellInstalledRule RebootRequiredCheck /HIDECONSOLE /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=""SQLEXPRESS3"" /SECURITYMODE=""SQL"" /SQLSVCACCOUNT=""NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"" /SAPWD=""MYPASS"" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=""BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS"" /ENABLERANU=1 /AGTSVCACCOUNT=""NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"" /TCPENABLED=1 /ERRORREPORTING=1 /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=""Automatic"""
    pro1.Start()

    Do While Not pro1.HasExited
        ctr = ctr + 1
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(ctr)
    Loop
End Sub
```

I successfully installed SQL Server using this code, but the application does not close when it is already finished.

I want a progress bar that will show the status of the process. I don't have idea how to do this.

Thanks in advance. Please leave a comment if my details are not enough to resolve my problem.

Comment: This just seems like a bad idea... like you're trying to use a server class database when an in-process database engine like Sql Server Compact Edition would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You could [close the Process when its finished](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Dim pro1 As System.Diagnostics.Process
    pro1 = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    pro1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    pro1.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD"
    pro1.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C SQLExpr_x64_enu.exe /QUIET=""TRUE"" /q /ACTION=Install /SkipRules=VSShellInstalledRule RebootRequiredCheck /HIDECONSOLE /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=""SQLEXPRESS3"" /SECURITYMODE=""SQL"" /SQLSVCACCOUNT=""NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"" /SAPWD=""MYPASS"" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=""BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS"" /ENABLERANU=1 /AGTSVCACCOUNT=""NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"" /TCPENABLED=1 /ERRORREPORTING=1 /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=""Automatic"""
    pro1.Start()

    Do While Not pro1.HasExited
        ctr = ctr + 1
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(ctr)
    Loop

    'Here close the process
     pro1.Close()
End Sub
```

For unattended SQL installs these are the command-line arguments I use:

\SQLEXPR.exe -q /norebootchk /qn reboot=ReallySuppress addlocal=all INSTANCENAME=${instance_name} SAPWD=${password} INSTALLSQLDIR=${install_dir} SQLBROWSERACCOUNT=NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE SQLACCOUNT=NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE AGTACCOUNT=NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE ASACCOUNT=NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE RSACCOUNT=NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE SQLBROWSERAUTOSTART=1 SQLAUTOSTART=1 AGTAUTOSTART=1 ASAUTOSTART=0 RSAUTOSTART=0 SECURITYMODE=SQL DISABLENETWORKPROTOCOLS=0 ERRORREPORTING=1 SQMREPORTING=0 ENABLERANU=0 ADDUSERASADMIN=0

> To troubleshoot change qn to qb, also see how my /norebootchk is different to your RebootRequiredCheck

You may also wish to investigate if the Exit Event gets called as per [Process.Exited Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx) and check why it isn't closing. You definitely dont want to force closing a process if it hasn't finished.

---

I dont think there is a way to have a Progress Bar to indicate how long an SQL Install is taking, same with estimating how long an SQL update will take. Refer to this method for a workaround: [VB.NET progressbar backgroundworker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206926/vb-net-progressbar-backgroundworker).