# Changing a Controls Visible Proprety doesn't redraw the Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls

i can't get the control visible property to change accordingly to my set value in code, and it looks ugly:

```
htmlLabel1.Visible = false;
htmlLabel1.Update();
htmlLabel2.Visible = true;
htmlLabel2.Update();
path = s;
if (Path.GetExtension(s) == ".iso")
{
   check = CalculateChecksum(s);
}
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Are there any alternatives to `Update()` that i can use to force redraw of the control ? (The control i am using is the HTMLLabel btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
htmlLabel2.Invalidate();
```

The Invalidate() method will cause the controls Paint event to fire (forcing the control to be redrawn).

---

MSDN Ref: [Control.Invalidate Method()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Invalidates the entire surface of the control and causes the control to be redrawn.

Comment: Nah it does work. just prove it to yourself with [Application.DoEvents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents) and never be using that sh*t again. Use a background thread instead. `Invalidate()` does work: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206926/vb-net-progressbar-backgroundworker

Comment: Wow i didn't know you had the all seeing eye of rae, when i say it doesn't work, it doesn't work: https://i.gyazo.com/83a2094629c7ae863cc4e1b882039f34.png  EDIT: this has nothing to do with a progress bar, nor update progress, i know how to update progress when Hashing a file, the problem at hand, is that in most of my projects i always have to give up on this feature because the `Visible` proprety doesn't work as it should.

Comment: OK, maybe there's something I am missing and this is the reason you put a bounty on it, could you please upload a [mcve] for me?

Comment: I sure hope that pastbin would be enough, i pasted the code to the whole DragDrop event: http://pastebin.com/mFUWxXmM

Comment: Well I dare say that an `Application.DoEvents` may just work in a drag/drop operation - though I did disclaim it earlier - can you please try that for us to knuckle down on the root cause, TIA

Comment: i appologize, i lost internet connexion, third world country problems, Welp, that did it, thank you very much, i'll mark your answer as the right one, please make sure to edit it ^_^ EDIT: i can't award my bounty yet, but in 10 hours i will, thank you again.

Comment: No worries mate it's 1am in Australia - I gotta go to bed for work tomorrow, will touch base then, cheers